# How can I attach to a process running on another computer from VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger

I have a C++ program that serves as an interpreter for a language my company defined. I want to be able to debug the code being executed through VSCode.

In order to do that, I developed a Debug Adapter Protocol server implementation in the interpreter (in C++) with the idea that VSCode would talk directly to this server, which would in return send all the data concerning the interpreted code.

This way I wouldn't have to build an entire Debugger Extension for VSCode (especially since I can't write JS).

Until now I made all this work thanks to the "debugServer" key of the launch.json file.

The following launch configuration is the one I used during my development :

```
{
    "type": "node",
    "request": "attach",
    "name": "name",
    "debugServer":12345
}
```

This all works well but it only works on the localhost for now.

Is there a way to tell the Debug Adapter client (built-in vscode) to send its requests to a specific IP address ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see in the docs, the only debugger that supports 'remote debugging' is the default Node.js ([see here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_remote-debugging)). If you are using the node debugger, then there should be a way to [set it up](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_remote-debugging)

If not, I'm guessing you'd have to implement your own [Debugger Extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/debugger-extension) following the API guidelines. I think the option you describe is mentioned [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/debugger-extension#alternative-approach-to-develop-a-debugger-extension) as `DebugAdapterServer`.

Hope that helps

Comment: I already tried the Node.js remote debugging but it did not seem to work. The messages sent by VSCode when trying to attach to a remote process were not following the DAP protocol format (there were extra double quotes surrounding one of the messages).
I found some other debugging extensions that support remote debugging (python or c++ ones for instance) so I would have enough examples if I were to implement my own debugger extension. But I still hope to find an easier way to use what is already built in the editor. Thanks for your answer anyway.

Comment: You are welcome! I'm right in the middle of writing a complete Language Server, just because there was actually no other alternative available...so I know what you are feeling. Sadly, it does sound like you are in a similar situation than mine... hope someone else can give a little bit more insight on the topic!